# Multiple Web Projects in a Single Solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a solution with two MVC Web Projects. The main project (HomeController) works as expected. When I hit the actions they find the views etc. However when hitting the second project controller (PortalController) it never finds the view, because I think its not looking in the second projects views folder.

How do I make MVC look in the correct view folder for the project of the controller I am hitting?

In my case I need them to be seperate web projects because project two is a generic admin system I want to use over several sites, and I want to just copy it in or reference the DLL.

How can I achieve this?

Here is a screenshot of my solution layout

[image]

Here is the error I get

[image]

Here is the code on the /Portal/Setup action in the controller. All I am doing is changing the URL to /Portal/Setup when on the Home/Index and it doesn't appear to find the corresponding view

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Setup()
    {
        if (_portalService.GetModerators().Any())
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Are you starting both web projects?

Comment: Both projects are in the same solution, and when I run it I believe it is finding the second project because initially it complained about not having the database connection string (used in the controller). When I resolved that, it is now unable to find the view.

Comment: Right-click the Solution in Solution Explorer and choose Properties. You can specify multiple startup projects in that dialog.

Comment: you might want to research `Areas` or `RazorGenerator` to combine multiple mvc projects into one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't hold two MVC projects in the same level, as an alternative, you could register the Typhoeus.Portal.Web as an MVC area, and calling /[AreaName]/Portal/Setup instead of calling /Portal/Setup.

To make Typhoeus.Portal.Web an MVC area, you can add PortalAreasRegistration inherits from AreasRegistration.

```
public class PortalAreasRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Portal";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Portal_default",
            "Portal/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Portal", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

In Typhoeus.Personal.Web, add Typhoeus.Portal.Web as a project reference, and register all MVC areas with `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` in the `Application_Start()` method of 'Global.asax.cs'.

After doing so, you can visit /Portal/Setup in this case /Portal/Portal/Step with the first `Portal` as area name, you can change this in `PortalAreasRegistration`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to ensure that both web projects are running. To set this as the default behavior when you are debugging, right click on your solution > Properties. The select Startup Project on the left.

This will give you the option to select your startup project, or to select multiple. In your case you'd want to select multiple startup projects, each of your web sites.

[image]

Comment: I was unaware of this option thanks, though it has not resolved the issue. When I run the solution now it automatically opens both websites in new tabs. However when I try to navigate to the URL's of the second project its still unable to find the view

Comment: can you expand your question with some more details? what are the page names, what's the code look like?

Comment: I have added two screenshots to the question. When run in isolation the "Portal" project works, just not when combined with my other project in the same solution

Comment: post some code that shows how you're linking to the other site

Comment: I am simply changing the URL in my browser to http://localhost:49957/Portal/Setup.

Comment: **post some code** we can't debug why it can't find `Setup` without it.

Comment: @TomMcClean on your screen you changed it not to  localhost:49957/Portal/Setup. You changed it to localhost:52246/Portal/Setup. Is it normal?)

Comment: I didn't notice that, so it seems that both web projects are running under different localhost ports? I was expecting them to be on the same address and that I could just change the route?

Comment: yes, they are two different sites, so how could they run on the same port?

Comment: Unfortunately I am learning MVC as I go, I didn't think that would be a problem as they are both different controllers; thanks for the help on this, ill have to redesign how I do this

Answer (score 1):

I bet you need to set the Project(s)|Start Action to point to the root url of the app so that when you hit F5 the root is always loaded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right -click on your projects -> property -> web ->project URL
you can find your second project URL and use it,  BUT after loading both projects 
 user: Dleh answered this part